# Decompressing data during selecting table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table for my forms.
I compressed the form templates when I inserted them into the database.

```
DECLARE @TemplateCompressed varbinary(MAX);
SET @TemplateCompressed = COMPRESS(N'<style></style><body><h1>Application Form</h1>...');
INSERT INTO Forms (Title,Template) VALUES ('Application Form',@TemplateCompressed);
```

Now, I want to decompress and read the form templates.

Here is my table:

| FormId | Title | Template |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Account Opening Form | 0x1F8B0800000000000400B361286... |
| 2 | Application Form | 0x1F8B0800000000000400B361286... |

I want decompress templates and list them as the following table:

| FormId | Title | Template |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Account Opening Form | <style>body{color:#242424;font-size:16px;... |
| 2 | Application Form | <style></style><body><h1>Application Form</h1>... |

How can I obtain the second table?

Comment: So what problem do you have with your code to do so? What is your question?

Comment: @Stu I want to the second table, which should obtained by decompressing the first table.

Comment: The `xml` data type is highly compressed anyway, you are probably not gaining much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decompress a compressed value you use `Decompress()`. Then of course you need to cast/convert the varbinary to a string:

```
declare @TemplateCompressed varbinary(max) = Compress(N'<style></style><body><h1>Application Form</h1>...');
insert into forms (Title,Template) values ('Application Form',@TemplateCompressed);

select *, Convert(nvarchar(max), Decompress(Template)) Result
from forms;
```

You might also what to investigate [table compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-ver16) which yields much better performance and compression than gzip.

Comment: Page compression won't help for LOB types such as `nvarchar(max)` or `xml` unless the values are small enough to fit in-row. Row compression does nothing.